# Initator and acceptor logout order in Quickfix

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

When I have a FIX session between acceptor and initiator which side in general should be sending logout message first?

Also, is it fine to set session times on acceptor and initiator side to the same hours? Or maybe initiator should be configured for the shorter period to keep the communication safe and clear from errors?

Comment: I may not understand your question but either side can initiate a logout, just depends on who is doing what.

Comment: My issue is that if the session times are set on both sides for the same hours then both sides at once send logouts, and both of them are rejected because they arrive after the session is already ended. So I'm asking whether the acceptor or initiator should have configured shorter session time. I cannot find anything about that in documentation.

Comment: @Michal Kordas, What I have seen is initiator time is before the market opening and after market closing. So,Logon is sent by initiator and Logout is sent by ECN (Acceptor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on real project experience,

- The connection was post trade feed, where our post trade gateways
  used to connect with ECN (Electronic communication networks) like
  Bloomberg, Tradeweb etc.
- The ECN used to act as Acceptor and our gateways used to act as
  initiator.
- As initiator, its our gateways responsibility to initiate the
  connection with ECN by sending LOGON message.
- The gateways used to send LOGON and LOGOUT half an hour before/After
  the markets open & closes respectively.

But in case there is some problem/error, even ECN used to send a LOGOUT message.

> So, there is no hard and fast rule, who should send LOGOUT message.